# Flutter change GNav tab from Button

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigation

I have 4 pages in a GNav() Bottom-Navigation-Bar and I would like to navigate to different page via click of a button.
I am aware that there might be similar questions on stackoverflow already, however I was unable to implement any of them successfully which is why I am posting here as my "last effort".

First off, my Class RootPage() which is where I am defining my GNav bar and the pages linked to each tab.

```
import 'package:anitan/pages/menu_bar_pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:anitan/pages/menu_bar_pages/search_page.dart';
import 'package:anitan/pages/menu_bar_pages/settings_pages/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RootPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage>{
  int currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = const [
    HomePage(),
    ProfilePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    SettingsPage()
  ];

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: pages[currentPage],
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15),
              child: GNav(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                color: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.green.shade800,
                gap: 8,
                onTabChange: (index) => setState(() => currentPage = index),
                selectedIndex: currentPage,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                tabs: const [
                  GButton(icon: Icons.home, text: "Home"),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.person, text: "My Page"),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.search, text: "Browse"),
                  GButton(icon: Icons.settings, text: "Settings"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Next up, the HomePage which has a button. When clicked, I want to change the selected tab of my GNav bar. Pushing the page etc. will lead to the Navigation Bar disappearing which is why this isn't an option.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key,});
 

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Home Page"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint("appBar Button");
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (() => print("Change Page Here")), child: Text("Change-Page")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried a few things like implementing a StreamController or using a GlobalKey. But I would like to the GNav Bar instead of using a Tab controller because of its design.

In theory, what I am trying to do seems simple:
I would like to currentPage to a new index and call setState() to show the changes.

Can anyone help me understand how I can access change the index and update the selected page in my RootPage?
I have spent 2 days looking into various solutions but I can't get any of them to work.

Many thanks!

Edit:
Please find the code of my main.dart below.

```
import 'package:anitan/pages/menu_bar_pages/root_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
//import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        home: RootPage(),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your main.dart code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the main.dart to the bottom of my question!

Comment: After reading all your comments, if I am not wrong, you need the bottom navigation bar in all pages. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct.
I need it in all of my pages.

And I was simply looking for a way to basicall change the tab-index of my rootPage to select another page from a button rather than the menu bar itself.

I was able to implement this now through the answer from Yeasin + some more steps (see my answer below)

Comment: For that, you can use the package persistent_bottom_nav_bar 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

`HomePage` is already a part of  `RootPage` which is needed to be on the same route.You can use callback method to handle click-event/changing page.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: widget.onTap, child: Text("Change-Page")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you will get a callback method while creating `HomePage`

```dart
 int currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(onTap:(){  
       // page 
    } ),

  ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!

While I am not getting any errors, the other page is not being opened by the onTap call.

I added some debugPrints to see what is happening:

It seems while the onTap from the button is being called, the onTap part inside rootPage is not being executed --> a debugPrint inside the onTap part of rootPage is not being printed

Comment: Update: It seems the issue was a missing () behind the onTap for the onPressed call --> ElevatedButton(onPressed: widget.onTap().

While I get the debugPrint feedback now, the page I want to open (SearchPage) is not being opened or rather refreshed. How can I setState() on the root page to show the SearchPage() instead of the HomePage() once onTap is called? Adding setState() as is to the onTap call will lead to an error: The instance member 'setState' can't be accessed in an initializer

Comment: if you use `onPressed: widget.onTap()` it will call the method on build instead of tap event

Answer (score 0):

Given the reply from Yeasin Sheikh I implemented a little workaround which seems to be working fine:

First, as recommended by Yeasin, I added a VoidCallback function onTap to my HomePage class:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  const HomePage({super.key, required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
```

Then I called this onTap function clicking the button:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: widget.onTap(), child: Text("Change-Page")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my rootPage class, I then created my HomePage.
When the onTap function of that page is being called, I am calling a method to refresh the page (setState) and changing the currentPage index as part of it.
This required me to initialize the List of my pages using "late".

```
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage>{
  int currentPage = 0;

  late List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(onTap:(){  
      _changePage(2);
    } ),
    const ProfilePage(),
    const SearchPage(),
    const SettingsPage()
  ];

  _changePage(int id){
    setState(() {
      currentPage = id;
    });
  }
```

To keep everything centralized, I switched to using the same method to update the index in the onTabChange part of the GNav bar as well.

```
onTabChange: (index) => setState(() => _changePage(index)),
```

Clicking the button now switches the page.
The bottom navigation bar (GNav) will stay on the screen and can be used as usual.

Thank you for your support in figuring this out!